# Parsing Simple JSON only with an array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I don't know much about JSON parseing.
The JSON API is like that.

```
[
   "Text A" , "Text B" , "Text C"
]
```

I want to get all the texts from api directly from server.

How can I get these texts (Text A ,Text B , Text C) as an array?

Comment: Post your proper  json response

Comment: I'm using this api
http://proverbs-app.antjan.us/
How can I parse them into an array

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi ..what do you mean by proper?

Comment: its a valid json...and basic structure is shown by original author

Comment: @LinLin you can also used List and add data to there like as  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add( jsonArray.getString(i) );
}

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple basic jsonarray...you need to take jsonarray object and store the whole jsonarray
then you need to iterate jsonarray indexes and save the string to string array

```
JSONArray mainjson=new JSONArray(<jsonstring>);
String text[]=new String[mainjson.length()];
for(int i=0;i<mainjson.length();i++)
{
     text[i]=mainjson.getString(i);
}
```

Comment: Sir , can you explain me more detail? 
I'm using this api
http://proverbs-app.antjan.us/

Comment: don;t understant what you said... acc to your json...all the text is saved inside stringarray "text" ..then you can use this array acc to your need

Comment: SIr , I want to fetch all the data from here.
http://proverbs-app.antjan.us/
And store all of them in an array

Comment: @AngadTiwari is correct LinLin you just have to insert your String of Array and run that code, i think it run correctly...
JSONArray mainjson=new JSONArray(<YOUR ARRAY STRING IS HERE>);
.
.

Comment: I want to fetch this string of array directly from server.

Comment: @LinLin ... your service return simple jsonarray response...each index of this jsonarray contain string...you just need to put this response to jsonarray object ..and iterate through it... thats it...what else i explain regarding this...this is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Using AQuery Library You can Do it Simply Like this, First Download Aquery.jar File & Paste it in your Lib Folder of Project.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
    String url = "YOUR URL HERE";

    aq.ajax(url, JSONArray.class, this,
            "jsoncallback");

}

public void jsoncallback(String url, JSONArray jsonArray, AjaxStatus status) {

    String[] values; // this array will store your Strings
    if (jsonArray != null)
    {

            try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                    {
                        value[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
                    }

                } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
                { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
    else 
    {
        // Json is Null
    }
}
```